# When i use lm.fit, i see that 2 coefficients (on a total of 35) are NA

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, missing-data

[image]I am regressing a matrix 62x35 on a vector with dimension 62. I can do the regression but then 2 of the 35 resulting coefficients are "NA". I cannot send the picture of the data here but i can send it to whoever could help me. Thanks!
P.S. i attach the correlation matrix of the 62x35 matrix, the NA coefficients are the ones for the two highlighted variables.

Comment: They’re likely perfectly correlated with other variables. Can you post a correlation matrix?

Comment: @DemetriPananos the correlation matrix will not easily tell you if a particular variable is predictable from a linear combination of other variables. But you're right, a 1 or -1 in the offdiagnoal of this matrix immediately tells us we have rank deficiency.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: The model matrix is rank deficient.

Long answer: The model matrix is, along with the intercept, the matrix formed by collating the variables as columns in a matrix. We call it $\mathbf{X}$. If any *one or more* variable(s) (including the intercept) within that matrix can *perfectly predict* any other variable in that matrix, the matrix is *rank deficient* and a unique ordinary least squares solution doesn't exist.

However, R provides you a solution anyway. This solution is the result of using a *quasi-inverse* to invert the matrix $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$. You can consider that the NA variables are set to 0 and exclude them from the analysis.

In general, maximum likelihood does not do well at estimating a large number of parameters at once. In your case, you have $p=36$ parameters (including the intercept) and only $n=62$ observations. In a perfectly balanced design, this is theoretically possible. However, in almost any SRS, this is going to result in rank deficiency. There are lots of posts on rank deficiency in this site. Please read them!

One of the earliest proposed solutions to this problem was a ridge estimator. The ridge estimator provides point estimates and predictions with much smaller MSE than maximum likelihood. That is to say, you swap an efficient biased estimator in place of an inefficient unbiased one.